# Canonical approach to display mgmt in Windows: User32 or DXGI?

Tags: winapi, direct3d, user32, dxgi

We publish an app for Windows 10, and part of what it does is *display management*; the kind of thing you normally go to **Display Settings** for. We add/remove displays from the desktop, arrange them, change size and orientation, etc.

Currently I'm using APIs from User32.dll for all of the above (`ChangeDisplaySettingsEx`, `EnumDisplayDevices`, `DEVMODE`, `DISPLAY_DEVICE`, etc).

Recently I was looking over a display management .NET library project on GitHub. I particularly noticed that the author(s) were using a lot of Direct3D/DXGI APIs. I've worked in Windows for decades, but I never had occasion to use Direct3D at all.

Much of the information and reference material I consulted before writing the User32-based code has been around since the early days of Windows. My current version works fine, but I'd like to feel confident that I'm not using an outdated or inferior approach.

If the standard **Display Settings** app in Windows 10 were written today, would the display-management functionality be done with Direct3D/DXGI API calls, or is User32 still considered the canonical approach?

Comment: As long as an API is not marked as deprecated it's ok to use it. You forgot an important one WinRT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.display.core Windows.Devices.Display.Core Namespace
The problem is, sometimes you need a bit of Win32, DirectX, WinRT, etc. I would personally favor WinRT since it's now possible to call it easily from Win32, I think Microsoft will mostly invest more in that, and also it uses all the others, including undocumented API you will never have access anyway.

Comment: The intention of DirectX and WinRT was to provide info, but not to actively modify machine configuration.  User32 is fine.